# Promisified cicle inside promisified cicle in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, bluebird

I'm having a problem with promises in NodeJS even thought I'm using Bluebird. In the following code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var google = require('utils/google');

// list of (max 60 * number of types defined) nearby places
var nearby_places = [];

Promise.each(config.type.nearby, function (type) {
    google.nearbySearch(request.query.lat, request.query.lng, request.query.rad, type)
        .then(function (places) {

            // list of (max 60) places
            var detailed_places = [];

            console.log('Found ' + places.length + ' places.');

            // Get full details of places and insert them into database
            Promise.each(places, function (place_id) {
                google.getPlaceDetails(place_id)
                    .then(function (res) {
                        detailed_places.push(res);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                })
                .then(function () {
                    // Push detailed places to nearby places
                    nearby_places = nearby_places.concat(detailed_places);
                });

             })
             .catch(function (err) {
                 console.log(err);
             });
        }).then(function () {
            // Returns (max 60 * number of types defined) nearby places
            return reply(nearby_places);
        });
```

It executes the `google.nearbySearch()` and prints somethings in there, so I know it's running. But when it ends, it doesn't waits for the inside `Promise.each(places, ...`. It goes directly to the `return reply(...` with `nearby_places` empty. Then, it shows me in the console `Found X places.`.

I don't think I fully understand Promises/Bluebird, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you do not `return` a `Promise` from `.then()` chained to `google.nearbySearch(request.query.lat, request.query.lng, request.query.rad, type)`.

You should be able to resolve issue by returning `Promise.each(places, function(){})` from `.then()` chained to initial `google.nearbySearch(request.query.lat, request.query.lng, request.query.rad, type)` call

```
return Promise.each(places, function(){})
```

Comment: You may also need to `return` `google.getPlaceDetails(place_id)` from within `.each()` call, _"If the iterator function returns a promise or a thenable, then the result of the promise is awaited, before continuing with next iteration."_ http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html

Comment: I also needed to `return google.nearbySearch(...` in addition to your answers. Thanks!